# Rosanov - Probability Theory Chapter 4 Question 5

Tags: probability-distributions, random-variables

I am trying to solve one of the questions in **Rosanov - Probability (Chapter 4 Question 5)**, but I am not exactly sure what the question is asking of me. The question is:

Random variable $E$ with probability density:

$$p(x) = ax^2\  e^{-kx}$$

The questions are:

Find $a$;

How can I find a when there are $2$ unknowns in the equation, $k$ and $a$?

Find the distribution of $E$;

Is this an equation, and if so how do I find it?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What is the support of $x$? If $\;0<x<\infty$, then $\;a=\dfrac12k^3$.

Comment: Yes that is the support of x. Can I ask how you derived that?

Comment: Using $\displaystyle\int_0^\infty p(x)\ dx=1$ and letting $u=kx$, you will get a gamma function.